# Static Images within scrollview

Tags: java, android, android-layout, scrollview

my intention is to have an image on the left or right with a scrollview taking up the remaining space. I want the images to remain static as the text is scrolled through. I don't really know where to begin with it to be honest - i searched around but no one seemed to ask or answer exactly what i was trying to do, and any manipulations i tried on their code failed. The orientation is forcibly landscape.

I tried this:

```
home_scroll.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(480, 800));
home_scroll.addView(home_linear, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

But the combination of textview and images prevents it from working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this layout. Image is on the left side with scroll view taking up remaining space.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image1" >
    </ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is fantastic, but for some reason my image still isn't appearing (I edited your code and included src/drawable, so I don't think that's the issue). When I edit the code further and manually input width+height into DP form inside the image view I then get the image - and the text is fine - but the image keeps resizing to small resolutions the higher DP i go. Is my image simply too big?

Comment: I don't know, what is the image resolution? In which drawable directory do you have this image?

Comment: It's in hdpi, well the image is 3000x4000 (I can hear you already!). But without all the padding it scales just perfectly and looks great, it just isn't positioning for some reason. I tried a smaller res and had the same issue (1200x900).

Comment: Maybe you should change the scale type setting for the image view.